# Can't change Foreground in DataGridTextColumn

Tags: asp.net, wpfdatagrid

So, this is my Datagrid

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="false" Height="270" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="503" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyVocabularyExam, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" >      
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Sprache1" Width="*" Header="Sprache1" Binding="{Binding Language1}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Sprache2" Width="*" Header="Sprache2" Binding="{Binding Language2, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="False" Foreground="{Binding LanguageColor}"/>        
        </DataGrid.Columns>    
    </DataGrid>
```

I´m binding a List to the Datagrid with following Properties

```
public class myVocabulary
{
    public string Language1 { get; set; }
    public string Language2 { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush LanguageColor { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to make an Vocabulary Exam. The first column is filled with words and the other Column have to be filled with the translation.
My only problem is, I can´t change the foreground of the wrong translations, which the user have typed.
After the user have filled the grid, he have to click on a button, which will check if everything is correct. The wrong words have to turn in a red color.

I have tried

MyVocabularyExam[i].LanguageColor = Brushes.Red;

MyVocabularyExam[i].LanguageColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

But that didn´t work.
So please someone help me ^^

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745132/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-cell-using-wpf-toolkit-datagrid

Answer (score 6):

I had to set `ElementStyle` explicitly to make it work:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
         <Setter Property="Foreground"
                 Value="{Binding Path=FontColor}"></Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

Maybe there is a better solution, but I stopped searching at this point.