# Blink WPF DataGrid cell based on data value

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf-binding, datatrigger, eventtrigger

#### Setup:

I have a DataGrid bound to a collection of POCOs, which implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface and fire PropertyChanged events. One of the properties is a double value, let's call it Price.

#### Goal:

When Price goes up, DataGrid cell displaying it should blink green, when it goes down it should blink red. By blink I mean change background color for certain (small) amount of time.

#### Problem:

I'm unable to achieve this, have tried using data triggers with specially added properties in the data object (eg. PriceUp and PriceDown), but the problem is when and how to reset these flags to false, so that subsequent change would again run the trigger. Pulsing the flag false then true on update doesn't work. EventTrigger (on TargetUpdated) is of no help either, as far as I can tell, since I can't combine it with data conditions.

Note:

I found similar (or same) [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481), but although marked as answered, it actually is not.

Comment: Hope this link helps you ! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745132/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-cell-using-wpf-toolkit-datagrid

Answer (score 0):

You should have on your viewmodel the old cell value for each price. Then you can use a variable that is the difference between the old status and the current to trigger a color animation.

Comment: What technique would I use for triggering the animation? The variable you mention would have a range of positive or negative values, how could I use it in a DataTrigger?